# setting openpyxl format from text to number

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an excel file and i am using openpyxl to input some data. the data is currently being entered as text. I am trying to do a loop so that my `matrix` can be inputted into an excel number type.
The matrix is added into the excel no problem however the values are stored as text and not numbers. how can i change this? I thought by setting `number_format` to 0 it would work but it doesn't seem to.

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix, 3):
    for col_num, item in enumerate(row, col_start - 12):
        ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=item).number_format = "0"
wb.save(excel_file_path_from_db)
```

The matrix is made from user input values from dropdown options:

```
<td id="row_1_col_3">
               <center>
                   <select style="background-color: #ceedd0;" id="row_1_select_3" onchange="changeSelect('row_1','_col_3','_select_3')" name="filter_for">
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="P">P</option>
             <option value="0">-</option>
             <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
</select></center>
```

I then access the values by:

```
matrix = ast.literal_eval(list(request.GET)[0])
```

Comment: Could you give values for `matrix`, so the problem can be reproduced? Also you can check what data type openpyxl thinks the cells should be by printing `ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num).data_type`. If it's a number, the value should be `n`.

Comment: great thanks i have added more details so hopefully you are able to replicate it. when i check the `data_type` as you suggested it comes up as 's'. i guess that's good because we now just need to change that `data_type` to 's'. but i dont know how to do that haha. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the datatype of `item` is String or a more general type.
I would suggest:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix, 3):
    for col_num, item in enumerate(row, col_start - 12):
        if is_number(item):
            ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=float(item))
            ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num).number_format = "0"
        else:
            ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=item)
wb.save(excel_file_path_from_db)
```

Comment: thanks for trying but it doesn't seem to work. I tested the data type of each element in the matrix and they are all strings. `print(ws.cell(column=col_num, row=row_num, value=item).data_type)` dont know how to convert them to number format

Comment: I think the `float()` should convert the string to number, but my if statement was wrong. I've added a new function I found on Stackoverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float